# Git - replace local branch with remote branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

I know this question has been asked but I can't seem to completely replace my local branch with my remote branch.  I had installed a 3rd party plugin in my local branch and am having trouble removing the installation; thus, I want to "start over" with the remote version of the branch.  The branch is called "dev" locally and "origin/dev" remotely.  I've tried three ways of replacing my local branch with the remote version:

```
1. git reset HEAD --hard

2. git reset --hard origin/dev

3. git checkout dev
   git fetch
   git reset --hard origin/dev
```

But reviewing the local code after the executing the above git commands, I can still see leftover files and folders from the plugin.

Using `git status`, I get `"Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.  Nothing to commit, working directory clean".`

Using `git status --ignored`, I get too many files to list... basically everything in my .gitignore file I believe.

I only want the code that exists in the remote dev branch and nothing else.

Can somebody help?

**Update:**

Turns out that the error that I was getting was due to a bunch of files in the directory, `root/var/cache/*`.  My `.gitignore` file contains the following entries:

```
/var/*
!/var/package
var/session/*
```

Trying the possible ways to restore the local dev branch from remote (listed in the question above as well as the proposed solutions below), the `root/var/cache` directory remained present; I had to manually delete it before my application started functioning again.  Looking at the github, the remote dev branch did not contain 'root/var/cache`.  Can anybody tell me why`root/var/cache` was not responding to the git commands for replacing the local branch with the remote version?

Comment: Just deleted everything and reclone?

Comment: The files from the plugin are not tracked by git, so that git does not touch them at all. Just delete them by hand.

Comment: I didn't want to delete and reclone because I have other branches in the repository that I need to keep.  I'm new a git but it's hard believe that there isn't an easy way of doing this.  Lesson learned: don't install vendor plugins that are 750 files that require you to "drag and drop" the files throughout your code.

Comment: Thanks, @Hong, but I've got 750 files scattered throughout my application.  Deleting manually would not be a good way for this project.  I seriously thought I could just "revert" to an old branch and not worry about uninstalling but I'm wondering if I accidentally "contaminated" the branch that I was planning on reverting to.

Comment: You can delete everything in your git repository, except `.git` folder. Then you can get everything back from `.git` folder. A single or several `rm -rf ...` commands seem not too much effort.

Comment: You need to add the output of `git status` and `git status --ignored` to the question and indicate what of the shown files you want to delete.

Comment: @AD7six - appreciate the suggestions.  I updated the question.  Any idea why the `root/var/cache/` directory was not removed when I was trying to replace the local dev branch with the remote version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From another branch (say master), reset your dev branch:

```
git branch -f dev origin/dev
```

Then, checkout dev and clean up your extra files:

```
git checkout dev
git clean -d -f
```

Comment: Thanks, @acanby, but the directory that was causing problems was not being removed; I had to manually remove that directory.  Any idea why the git commands wasn't deleting that directory? Please see updated question for details.

Answer (score 4):

Try `git clean -fx`. That will remove all untracked files, even if they're mentioned in `.gitignore`.

Comment: but before doing that remember to backup all necessary files. Sometimes IDEs keeps information in `.hidden_directories` about how your project is configured. For example `.idea` in case of PyCharm/Webstorm etc.

Comment: Thanks, Wouter - tried your solution but there was a directory (that was causing me problems) that was not removed; updated the question.  Any idea what I was doing wrong?

Comment: Git does not track directories, only files. If a filename has a path component that does not exist, then git will create the missing parts, but otherwise will ignore them. You can add the -d switch to clean empty directories as well.